# No C terminal on furnace

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

This old Lennox furnace has no c terminal. I can run a wire directly from the furnace to the thermostat. Question is, which terminal do I hook it to? 
[image: s2]

Comment: Look more widely, it may not be in the usual group of terminals, since traditional thermostats did not need it.  Is there a transformer in the furnace somewhere?

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for the furnace and/or photos of the wiring at the furnace?